# node.js express router to render data from executed SQL statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, azure-sql-database, ejs

I am trying to build `node.js + express` application which consumes the data from SQL server database. But I have a problem in getting the response for my `executeStatement()` which is within `app.get()` router function. I expect my code to render an array object which I could  simply use in my `ejs` template or view. As shown in the code below `column.value` is the main array of object that I want to use on the frontend.

PS: I am fairly new to the world of programming.Thank you for your help!

```
var express = require('express');
var tediousExpress = require('express4-tedious');
var app = express();
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', './views')

var config = { 'contains my credentials'  }
var connection = new Connection(config);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.sql = tediousExpress(connection);
    next();
});


app.get('/products', function (req, res ) {

    /* I want to get column.value object to be rendered to my frontend 
       I already used res.json() here but it returns nothing*/ 

    function executeStatement() {
        request = new Request("select count * from table where ArticleId= 
                24588 for json path", function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log('total rows fetched ') ;
          }
          connection.close();
        });

       request.on('row', function(columns) {
          columns.forEach(function(column) {
            if (column.value === null) {
              console.log('NULL');
            } else {
                 column.value ;       
                }
          });

        });
      connection.execSql(request) ; 
       }  

});
```

Comment: does returning `column.value` from the function work? i.e. `return column.value`. Then calling the `executeStatement()` function should give you the array to iterate

Comment: what exactly you want ? In else statement you are just writing "column.value" you have to use res.render method to render . Also make sure you are getting data in "column.value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render within your callback to `row` event:

```
app.get('/products', function (req, res ) {
  // assuming you get the datas in column.value
  request = new Request("select count * from table where ArticleId=24588 for json path", function(err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('total rows fetched ') ;
    }
    connection.close();
  }

  request.on('row', function(columns) {
    const datas = []; // <-- array to hold values
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
      if (column.value === null) {
        console.log('NULL');
      } else {
        datas.push(column.value);
      }
    });
    res.render('myView', { datas })
  });
  connection.execSql(request);
}
```

In your `view`, you can access the `datas` like:

```
<% datas.forEach(value => { %>
  // do something like
  // <p><%= value %></p>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. This is already very helpful but I still have an error which says ` RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Final state `. I can find the solution to this on GitHub but I am too dumb to change my codes that could let this code run smoothly. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are not rendering any data to be passed to the front-end, also you aren't returning the array from the function.

To neaten up your logic, you should have something like this:

```
app.get('/products', function(err, data) {
  res.render('products', { arrData: executeStatement() }, function(err, data) {
    // ...
  })
})

executeStatement() { // ... }
```

Then in `executeStatement()` change `column.value` to `return column.value`

In your front-end template you can then iterate the data and output it as you wish:

```
<% arrData.forEach(value => { %>
  // do something with each value
<% }) %>
```